# Android 7+: Multi-window detection with Cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova

how are folks handling android’s [multi-window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) support in cordova or using browser events? Specifically, I am trapping the `pause` event in my app and doing cleanup because when the app is *not* running in multi-window mode, it actually means the app is going to the background. I use this callback to clear up some expensive memory resources (which includes live video feeds being displayed).

However, in multi-window mode, when you lay two apps next to each other and perform any activity on the other app, the browser generates the `pause` event. Obviously, in this case, I don’t want to do the cleanup because the UI is still visible.

So the question is, does cordova offer a way to:

- Either detect if the app is running in multi-window mode
- Or, differentiate between a `pause` event and a `stop` event (as described in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191627/multi-window-prevent-the-out-of-focus-app-from-pausing) SO thread)

I noticed [a note](https://github.com/apache/cordova-discuss/blob/master/proposals/android-n-support.md)  in cordova-discuss but the author doesn’t mention which one line change. I only found a change related to androidresizable being set to true but that is not my problem. The app does take its window in multi-window and doesn’t go full screen. Its the events that are causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together a cordova plugin that returns true if the app is in multi-window and false if not. Also allows you to trap `onStop` and `onStart` which are important in multi-window mode, specifically.

This is my first plugin and if its bad, feel free to PR and improve.

Link: https://github.com/pliablepixels/cordova-plugin-multi-window